# parallel query to spark with sqlcontext

Tags: apache-spark, parallel-processing, pyspark, amazon-emr, bigdata

We are trying to run ETLs on spark in the EMR. There are about 2000 million events in S3 as gzipped json line. They are about 30 files in total. I am using pyspark.

This is the code,

```
def value_to_list(columns):
    def value_map(values):
        data = []
        for val in values:
            d = val.asDict()
            data.append([d[column] for column in columns])
        return data

    return value_map


def main():
    sc = SparkContext()
    sql_context = SQLContenxt(sc)

    all_events = SQLContenxt(sc).read.json("s3n://...", schema=StructType(fields), timestampFormat="yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")
    all_events.registerTempTable('allevents')

    for event_type in event_types:
        process_event(sc, event_type, "allevents")


def process_event(sparkcontext, etype, tablename):
    query = "select app_id, source, type, {time_cols}, count(*) as total " \
            "from {table} where  type = '{event_type}' " \
            "group by app_id, source, type, {time_cols}"
    time_cols_spec = [('hour', 'day', 'month', 'year'),
                      ('day', 'month', 'year'),
                      ('month', 'year'),
                      ('year')]

    for time_cols in time_cols_spec:
        final_query = query.format(time_cols=", ".join(time_cols),
                                   table=tablename,
                                   event_type=etype)
        dataframe = sql_context.sql(final_query)

        dataframe.rdd.groupBy(lambda r: r['app_id'])\
            .mapValues(value_to_list(['source'] + time_cols))\
            .saveAsTextFile("s3n://...")
```

So, we have about 30 types of events and for each event I'm aggregating in 4 combination for hour, day, month and year. So 4 query for each. And we have about 2000M of events in total.

I am running this with on

- AWS EMR (5.0.3)
- Apache Spark 2.0.1
- 1 master, 2 worker
- each machine is `m3.2xlarge`
- total memory is 90GB

The problem is, the final save is taking long time. Last time I queried it took 14 hours for 2 time combination and one event :(

I know I am not going in parallel fashion. The loop is sequential. And there are 2 loops. But I expect `rdd,groupBy`, `mapValues` to run parallel. When I see the event timeline, I see its the `saveAsTextFile` that is taking 99% of the time. Probably its because spark executes lazily.

I need to make this process parallel and fast. How can i do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are 4 major optimizations you can apply:

1. You are performing aggregations on plain json files which are not optimized for making queries. Rewrite them to parquet, repartition by event type and store on S3 - they will take less space and you application will get a nice speed boost.
2. Increase parallelism. There is no need to have a driver (master) on such powerfull VM, instead spawn one smaller instance (`m3.medium` for example) and use all 3 big ones for workers.
3. Replace RDD API calls with Dataframes: `.rdd.groupBy().mapValues()` can be replaced by `.groupBy(dataframe.app_id).agg(collect_list())` and then some mapping.
4. You can perform query on raw data for (hour, day, month, year) dataset and then use this aggregates to callculate all remaining queries for given event.

Comment: This answer gave me a lot of hint. It helped me a lot. Hence I am marking this as "answer".